# How to combine an Expandable Table with an Expansion Panel in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to combine two separate Vuetify functionalities into one:

1. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables --> Expandable Rows Table (but ideally with more than one data row upon expansion)
2. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels --> External Control Expansion Panel

Ultimately, the goal is to have a table that looks like this (**Grouping Table with expand/collapse all** one): https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/aadaJx

The issue with this table is that despite fitting the code into my project, certain functionalities don't work -- such as clicking to open and close a table. I believe this is due to this being a different version of Vue than what I'm using, which is the most up to date, as I spotted some old styles.

I've tried a bunch of things, but my most successful attempt is creating a table within a table. Here is the code for that:

```
<template>
<v-container>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="projects"
    :expanded="expanded"
    item-key="name"
    show-expand
    class="elevation-1"
    @click:row="clicked"
  >
    <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers }">
      <td :colspan="headers.length">
      <v-data-table
  :headers="peopleHeaders"
  :items="people"
  item-key='name'
  hide-default-footer
  class='elevation-1'>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
        <tr>
          <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{props.item.major}}</td>
          <td>{{props.item.preference}}</td>
          <td>
          <v-btn color='success'>Accept</v-btn>
          <v-btn color='error'>Reject</v-btn>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
  </td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Status', value: 'Status' },
      ],
      projects: [
        {
          name: '#this is the project they applied to',
          Status: 'Status: Pending',
        },
      ],
      peopleHeaders: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Major',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'major',
        },
        {
          text: 'Preference',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'preference',
        },
      ],
      people: [
        {
          name: 'BORB',
          major: 'SWE',
          preference: 'idk',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clicked(value) {
      this.expanded.push(value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Any advice for how to combine the two features to achieve the table desired would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem today and found a solution. Not sure if the op had solved the problem already or not, but let me provide my solution:

```
<template>
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-title>First table</v-expansion-panel-title>
      <v-expansion-panel-text>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items"></v-data-table>
      </v-expansion-panel-text>
    </v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-title>Second table</v-expansion-panel-title>
      <v-expansion-panel-text>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items"></v-data-table>
      </v-expansion-panel-text>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        // Define the items property here
        {
          name: 'African Elephant',
          species: 'Loxodonta africana',
          diet: 'Herbivore',
          habitat: 'Savanna, Forests',
        },
        {
          name: 'African Elephant',
          species: 'Loxodonta africana',
          diet: 'Herbivore',
          habitat: 'Savanna, Forests',
        },
        {
          name: 'African Elephant',
          species: 'Loxodonta africana',
          diet: 'Herbivore',
          habitat: 'Savanna, Forests',
        },
        {
          name: 'African Elephant',
          species: 'Loxodonta africana',
          diet: 'Herbivore',
          habitat: 'Savanna, Forests',
        },
      ],
      headers: [
        { title: 'Name', key: 'name' },
        { title: 'species', key: 'species' },
        { title: 'diet', key: 'diet' },
        { title: 'habitat', key: 'habitat' },
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```